# EclipseLink generates new alias for tables causing PostgreSQL exception

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, eclipselink, jpql

I have a named query which joins on **two** foreign keys for table receiver_list_property_values. This is needed to match the correct property and value for the receiver. Database model is a dynamic table.

```
SELECT l.name, r.firstName, p.name, v.value 
FROM ReceiverList l 
    LEFT JOIN l.receivers rl 
    LEFT JOIN rl.receiver r 
    LEFT JOIN l.properties p 
    LEFT JOIN p.receiverListPropertyValues v ON p.id=v.property.id AND rl.id=v.receiver.id 
WHERE l.id=:id ORDER BY r.firstName
```

However, this join on two columns produces a query where JPA aliases tables receiver_list_receivers and receiver_list_properties as t6 and t5 even though both tables are already aliases as t2 and t3. This causes the **dreadful** PotgreSQL error:

> Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: **ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "t5"**
>     Position: 389
>   Error Code: 0
>   Call: SELECT t0.NAME, t1.first_name, t3.NAME, t4.VALUE FROM receiver_lists t0 LEFT OUTER JOIN receiver_list_receivers t2 ON (t2.receiver_list_id = t0.ID) LEFT OUTER JOIN receivers t1 ON (t1.ID = t2.receiver_id) LEFT OUTER JOIN receiver_list_properties t3 ON (t3.receiver_list_id = t0.ID) LEFT OUTER JOIN receiver_list_property_values t4 ON ((t4.receiver_list_property_id = t3.ID) AND ((t3.ID = t5.ID) AND (t2.ID = t6.ID))), **receiver_list_receivers t6, receiver_list_properties t5** WHERE ((t0.ID = ?) AND ((t5.ID = t4.receiver_list_property_id) AND (t6.ID = t4.receiver_list_receiver_id))) ORDER BY t1.first_name

How do I make this work?

Entity *ReceiverList*

```
private String name;  
private List<ReceiverListReceiver> receivers;  
private List<ReceiverListProperty> properties;
```

Entity *Receiver*

```
private String firstName;  
private List<ReceiverListReceiver> receiverLists;
```

Entity *ReceiverListReceiver*

```
private Receiver receiver;  
private ReceiverList list;
```

Entity *ReceiverListProperty*

```
private String name;  
private String type;  
private ReceiverList receiverList;  
private List<ReceiverListPropertyValue> receiverListPropertyValues;
```

Entity *ReceiverListPropertyValue*

```
private ReceiverListReceiver receiver;  
private ReceiverListProperty property;
```

[image]

Comment: "JPA" doesn't do that (being simply a series of interfaces and annotations); your JPA implementation does ... but you need to say which one it is. Also providing an outline of each class (just include the relation fields) may help people's understanding

Comment: It is EclipseLink. I attached the schema.

Comment: Added relevant class members.

Comment: Looks like it's adding those tables after the join that requires them. Try changing `v.property.id` and `v.receiver.id` to `v.list_properties_id` and `v.list_has_receiver_id`. Giving it direct native columns has worked for me in the past, before we moved entirely to native queries to gain some performance.

Comment: It doesn't seem that I can use direct column names. The following is thrown: ```Exception Description: Object comparisons can only be used with OneToOneMappings.  Other mapping comparisons must be done through query keys or direct attribute level comparisons. ``` Native query would work but I'd try to avoid it if possible.

Comment: clearly an EclipseLink bug, that ought to be reported as a minimum; doesn't help you resolve it (other than to use the native query as a workaround).

Comment: What EclipseLink version is this?

Comment: Eclipselink 2.6.1. My understanding is that PostgreSQL wants to have every single table used in the query inside a FROM clause while the same query would probably? work on something like MySQL. So it is PostgreSQL specific bug in Eclipselink but that is just my assumption.